# Resume by RTC to guarantee software updates

Tags: bios, patch-management, wake-on-lan, realtime

I am maintaining around 100 user workstations with various software and operating systems.

I use a WSUS Server for Windows updates and I have a set of custom scripts for other software.

WSUS will push updates at 3am, and the scripts run an hour later with a scheduled shutdown.

My problem is forcing my users to always leave their computers on, many forget when their shift ends, and they just lock their station and leave for the day.

I'd like to take the task out of their hands and be sure all of my stations are getting the patches they require.  I could disable the user's ability to shut down, but to have the machines wake for patches would be nice for some added power saving.

I investigated using Wake On LAN to schedule a 2am wake up call.
Then I played around with Resume with RTC, which seems like it could be perfect for my daily early morning boots.

I'm sure I am not the only one in this situation, any suggestions for alternatives?  Has any one used a specific Resume on RTC time with success?

Thanks in advance for advice!